# How to deploy a new SSRS report in Existing Sharepoint page?

Tags: sharepoint, ssrs-2012

I am new to sharepoint, I have sharepoint page where some reports are already deployed. In the welcome page there is separate pane (With multiple Sections) in left corner with list of report names. Now I need to deploy a new report and add the report in one of the sections in the left pane.

Answer (score 1):

I removed steps for fine tweeking how ssrs renders on sharepoint but if you need those steps let me know. Here are screen shots for rest of them.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]